# WMS tiles disappear when zooming out in geoserver

Tags: image, openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

I have published a layer in geoserver which has approximately 25000 features.when  added this layer as wms services with openlayers 3,some of the tiles are missing when zoomed out.The image is blur until I zoom in to each feature.I want the image to be clear (without blur) from any zoom level.

PS:I am not applying any scale based rules for the layer.

Comment: You need to post more information like a screen print of the blur and code for how the layer is configured.  Did you look at the console for messages?? and also check under the network tab which will show you file requests to the server

Comment: This question would be better asked on GIS.stackexchange.com